# clover.xml not found - Jenkins Build

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, clover

after changing to SonarRunner for my Jenkins-Builds there is a problem with my automatically generated reports.

I generate these reports from the clover.xml but I got this problem in my Jenkins Job:

```
13:15:00.760 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.clover.CloverSensor
13:15:00.760 WARN  - Clover XML report not found
13:15:00.760 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.clover.CloverSensor (done) | time=1ms
13:15:00.760 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor
13:15:00.761 INFO  - parsing d:\seu\jenkins\workspace\dev2015.0.0 module.fakturierung.Buch.Tabelle.Test.Testjob\target\surefire-reports
13:15:00.761 ERROR - Reports path not found or is not a directory: d:\seu\jenkins\workspace\dev2015.0.0 module.fakturierung.Buch.Tabelle.Test.Testjob\target\surefire-reports
13:15:00.761 INFO  - Sensor SurefireSensor (done) | time=1ms
```

Here my sonar-project.properties:

```
# required metadata
sonar.projectKey=de.adnova:module.fakturierung:test
sonar.projectName=module.fakturierung Testjob
sonar.projectVersion=2015.0.0-SNAPSHOT

# path to source directories (required)
sonar.sources=src/module.fakturierung

# exclusions from path
sonar.exclusions=**/src/generated/java/**, **/test/**, **/clover/**
#clover
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=clover 
sonar.clover.reportPath= D:/SEU/Jenkins/workspace/dev2015.0.0 module.fakturierung.Buch.Tabelle.Test.Testjob/src/module.fakturierung/target/site/clover/clover.xml
```

SonarQube 5.2 (Clover-Plugin 3.1)

Maven 2.3

I tried a lot but nothing worked.Thanks!

Comment: hard to help you out here... are you 100% sure the path in your configuration is correct ? do you have any issue when running the analysis locally ?

Comment: I am 100% sure. I looked for the XML file on my Jenkins Slave and found it in the declared folder. 
When I try to open it per URL:

"http:// se03/sonarqube/api/resources?resource=de.adnova:module.fakturierung:test&format=xml" it work. But when i add &metrics=tests it went wrong. 
Mysteriously &metrics=coverage works fine. I am realy confused.